# How to set SelectedValue of DropDownList in GridView EditTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, sqldatasource

I am trying to do [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402288/using-dropdownlist-in-edittemplates-of-a-gridview) as asked earlier. The only difference that I found is additional List item that was included in above code.

I tried to use `AppendDataBoundItems=true` but it is still not working. I also want to set the its default value to the value that was being displayed in label of itemtemplate i.e. DropDownList's `SelectedValue='<%# Eval("DepartmentName") %>'` but thie property is not available to me in dropdownlist.
What could be the reason. ??

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment_Edit" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="dsDepartment_Edit" DataTextField="DepartmentName" 
        DataValueField="PK_DepartmentId">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsDepartment_Edit" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BlackHillsConnect %>"  
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="sp_GetDepartmentDropDown" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>                                 
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDepartmentName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DepartmentName") %>' >
    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I am using `GridView`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DataValueField` seems to be wrong - shouldn't it be `DepartmentId`? Similarly, you need to have  `SelectedValue='<%# Eval("**DepartmentId**") %>'` - `DepartmentName` would be the `SeletectText`.

Comment: this is where i am in trouble. No such is property is getting visible to me i.e. SelectedValue or SelectedText, so that I can assign some value to them. About DataValueField, yes you are right it should be primary key. But not a part of discussion until these two properties gets available to me.

Comment: VS Designer may not be showing you the property in intelli-sense but its there. There are two properties - SelectedValue and SelectedIndex. What happens if you write SelectedIndex='<%# Eval('DepartmentId') %>'?

Comment: My mistake - it should have been as SelectedValue = '<%# Eval('DepartmentId') %>'.

Answer (score 4):

The use of the `GridView_DataBound` event handler solves the problem.

In your case you will need to add a `HiddenField` to store the `PK_DepartmentId` value:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="gvExample_DataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment_Edit" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsDepartment_Edit"
          DataTextField="DepartmentName" DataValueField="PK_DepartmentId">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDepartmentId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("PK_DepartmentId") %>' />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsDepartment_Edit" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BlackHillsConnect %>"
          ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="sp_GetDepartmentDropDown" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDepartmentName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DepartmentName") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void gvExample_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvExample.Rows)
  {
    DropDownList ddlDepartment = gvRow.FindControl("ddlDepartment_Edit") as DropDownList;
    HiddenField hfDepartmentId = gvRow.FindControl("hfDepartmentId") as HiddenField;

    if (ddlDepartment != null && hfDepartmentId != null)
    {
      ddlDepartment.SelectedValue = hfDepartmentId.Value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you guys suggesting to use loops, when there is a `GridView` method specifically made for when a row's condition changes - the `RowDataBound()`?

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)e.Row;
            HiddenField hfAgentID = (HiddenField)gvRow.FindControl("hfAgentID");
            if (hfAgentID != null)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    DropDownList ddlAgent = (DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("ddlAgent");
                    ddlAgent.SelectedValue = hfAgentID.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your grid there is an event called `ItemCommand`. Create a method for it:

```
protected void Grid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
```

Now simply create a case statement that will recognize when the user has clicked the edit button on the grid:

```
 case Grid.EditCommandName:     
//set a member variable to the string of the cell you are editing.
//something like: mString = e.item..["Column"].toString();                  
                   break;
```

Now you have a member variable set to the string you want to be selected before the dropdown is even loaded/prerendered. Use the event `OnPrerender` or `OnLoad` for the `dropdownbox` and set the selected item to this String.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best i have found....

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        RadioButtonList rbl = gvRow.FindControl("rblPromptType") as RadioButtonList;
        HiddenField hf = gvRow.FindControl("hidPromptType") as HiddenField;

        if (rbl != null && hf != null)
        {
            if (hf.Value != "")
            {
                //clear the default selection if there is one
                rbl.ClearSelection();
            }

            rbl.SelectedValue = hf.Value;
        }
    }
}
```