# How do I maintain the selected item in GridView DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My problem is I am not able to retain the item in the gridview after the Gridview_RowEditing event.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeading" HeaderText="Get Alerts By SMS"
                                ItemStyle-CssClass="gridValue" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblAlertBySMSGeofence" runat="server" Text=' <%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("alertBySMS")))) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAlertBySMSGeofence" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                        CssClass="gridValue">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"/>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeading" />
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridValue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**EDIT**

```
    protected void grdGeofence_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdGeofence.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
        grdGeofence.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        List<COMMONGeofenceAlert> geofenceData = new BLsmsalertdetail().getGeofencealertDetail(Session["sessaccountid"].ToString(), txtdeviceID.Text);
        for (int y = 0; y < geofenceData.Count; y++)
        {
            geofenceData[y].vehicleNumber = ddlVehicleNumber.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
        grdGeofence.DataSource = geofenceData;
        grdGeofence.DataBind();
    }

protected void grdGeofence_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdGeofence.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    string id = grdGeofence.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

    Label lblVehicle = (Label)row.FindControl("lblVehicleGeofence");
    TextBox mobileNumber = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMobileGeofence");
    TextBox EmailID = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmailGeofence");
    DropDownList ddlAlertBySMS = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAlertBySMSGeofence");
    DropDownList ddlAlertbyEmail = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAlertByeEmailGeofence");
    DropDownList AlertAtGeofenceEnter = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAlertGeofenceEnter");
    DropDownList alertAtGeofenceExit = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAlertGeofenceExit");
    DropDownList ddlAddress = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlGeofenceAddressGrid");
    BLsmsalertdetail detail = new BLsmsalertdetail();

    int i = updateGeofence(id, mobileNumber.Text, EmailID.Text, ddlAlertBySMS.SelectedItem.Value, ddlAlertbyEmail.SelectedItem.Value, AlertAtGeofenceEnter.SelectedItem.Value, alertAtGeofenceExit.SelectedItem.Value, ddlAddress.SelectedItem.Text);
    if (i == 1)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Success!!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Error!! Could not Update the value.')", true);
        }

        grdGeofence.EditIndex = -1;
        List<COMMONGeofenceAlert> geofenceData = new BLsmsalertdetail().getGeofencealertDetail(Session["sessaccountid"].ToString(), txtdeviceID.Text);
        for (int y = 0; y < geofenceData.Count; y++)
        {
            geofenceData[y].vehicleNumber = ddlVehicleNumber.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
        grdGeofence.DataSource = geofenceData;
        grdGeofence.DataBind();
}

protected void grdGeofence_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (grdGeofence.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlAddress = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlGeofenceAddressGrid");
            List<COMMONsmsalertdetail> getSmsDispatcherData = new BLsmsalertdetail().getSMSalertDetail(Session["sessaccountid"].ToString());

            for (int i = 0; i < getSmsDispatcherData.Count; i++)
            {
                ddlAddress.Items.Add(new ListItem(getSmsDispatcherData[i].place, getSmsDispatcherData[i].place));
       }
            //ddlAddress.DataSource = getSmsDispatcherData;
            //ddlAddress.DataTextField = "place";
            //ddlAddress.DataValueField = "place";
            //ddlAddress.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

The database return 0/1 depending upon the situation and I convert it into Yes and No using boolean expressions.

I want to keep the value of `"lblAlertBySMSGeofence"` as the selected text of the dropdownlist `"ddlAlertBySMSGeofence"`

I have seen many solution of many websites including SO. But the method are too  lengthy and are also not in context with my situation.
I have around 100 dropdownlists and I cannot rewrite the code again and again..

Is there a simpler way to do it.?

Comment: on row databound u can do it....but if change on front end than u to  enable AutoPostback True of ddl and bind grid view again

Comment: Ho can i do it? On row edit.. Label gets lost  I am not able to retrieve its value..

Comment: Try to set the value of dropdown in `RowDataBound` event of gridview.

Comment: @techdo For every dropdown.. I mean 100 dropdowns?

Comment: Why gridview binding is done in event `grdGeofence_RowEditing`? Is it necessary?

Comment: Dont you want the textboxes in  <EditItemTemplate> to have values when the gridviewrow is in edit mode?

Comment: i think u r using a good method bcz ur dropdown is in edit template...so setrting it value to direct to ur label is tricky in anycase ur gridview is binding...so no probem with current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add property `SelectedValue='<%#Eval("alertBySMS")%>'` for `DropDowList` `ddlAlertBySMSGeofence`. Check the link [How to set SelectedValue of DropDownList in GridView EditTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474933/how-to-set-selectedvalue-of-dropdownlist-in-gridview-edittemplate) for more details.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAlertBySMSGeofence" runat="server"
      AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("alertBySMS")%>'  
      CssClass="gridValue">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
         <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: The option selected value is not available.. see this http://i.imgur.com/B2ClDAU.jpg

Comment: It's not an issue... It won't come by default. You just add that property and check.

Comment: Thank you so much..!! If I could give you 100+

Comment: Sweet mother of god..! You made it so simple..! Thanks a lot again.! I was badly stuck..